# Making one of multiple TextView s in a TableRow not to wrap text

Tags: android, android-layout

Given the below TableLayout, TableRow, how do we make the text in textView2 not to wrap text while make the text in textView3 do wrap text ?

```
<TableLayout
        style="@style/stdTableLayout" >

        <TableRow
            style="@style/standardTableRow" >
            <TextView
                style="@style/someActivityTableTextLeft"
                android:text="Some Title"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/someActivityTableTextRight"
                android:text="A very very very long text to be displayed here"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The styles for `standardTableRow`, `someActivityTableTextLeft` and `someActivityTableTextRight` are defined as below.

```
<style name="stdTableLayout" parent="">
    <item name="android:layout_width" >match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height" >match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft" >10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight" >10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="standardTableRow" parent="">
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
</style>

<style name="someActivityTableTextLeft" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:layout_width" >wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight" >1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor" >@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft" >0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
        <item name="android:gravity" >left</item>
    </style>

    <style name="someActivityTableTextRight" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:layout_width" >wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight" >1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor" >@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight" >5dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity" >right</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

make `textView2` `singleline` to `true`.

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

In `Table Layout` you can also use [shrinkColumn](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns) property to shrink column . in your case it is second textview

```
<TableLayout style="@style/stdTableLayout"  shrinkColumn="1">
```

Also see [strechColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns),[collapseColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:collapseColumns)

Comment: `android:singleLine = "true"` on `textView2` doesn't help -- it formats the text to fit in a single line by appending ... beyond what can be fitted in a single line.